# Google Earth placemark exclusion zone

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I'm developing an application using the Google Earth plugin that involves a good amount of placemarks. I was wondering if there was way to draw a polygon (or something of the sort) to filter out all placemarks outside of the polygons boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can draw a polygon, and then depending how you created your placemarks you could filter them out clientside (if created using javascript) or serverside (if loading via a dynamic KML).

Because Google Earth can display a lot of placemarks, and also because KML supports concepts like regionated network links to help you display the appropriate amount of placemarks as you zoom in or out, if you want more details it would be useful to know what you're trying to accomplish and why you think a polygon filter is the best way to work around whatever bottleneck or other limitation you think might exist.

Comment: Since I am dealing with a large quantity (couple thousand) of dynamically created and updated placemarks (updated every few seconds), I want the user to be able to select a specific area using a polygon and have the placemarks that fall inside the shapes border to continually get refreshed while having placemarks outside of the border stop getting updates. This is in an effort to minimize the tax on the network.

Comment: I don't know if you control the server.  But assuming so, just have the user draw a polygon, and pass the coordinates back to the server, and have the server only return the appropriate points.  If you don't control the server, then you still need to give more info (for example you didn't answer if you are creating placemarks using JS or just loading KML).